# nebula integration test with java

Tags: nebula-graph, nebula-test

I am a java developer

in my project, I want to have an integration test with nebula

I want to know more about samples and best practices for Seed info in my DB with the Factory then Assert them.

is there any solution?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the project of ngbatis, where it leveraged the nebula-docker-compose to bootstrap a cluster in container and talk to it in the test.

https://github.com/nebula-contrib/ngbatis/blob/master/.github/workflows/pull_request.yml